# What is the syntax for deleting an array element if you don't know its index?

Tags: arrays, raku

You can use the [adverb `:delete`](https://docs.raku.org/language/subscripts#index-entry-subscript_adverb_%3Adelete-%3Adelete) in Perl 6 to delete an array element if you know its index:

```
my @letters = <a b c>; @letters[0]:delete; say @letters
# OUTPUT: «[(Any) b c]␤»
```

However, you can't do that if you don't know the index:

```
my @letters = <a b c>; $_:delete if $elem eq 'a' for @letters
#ERROR! → Variable '$_:delete' is not declared
```

If you declare the loop variable `is rw` still the same problem:

```
my @letters = <a b c>; for @letters -> $l is rw { $l:delete if $l eq 'a' }; say @letters
#ERROR! → Variable '$l:delete' is not declared
```

There does not seem to be another way of deleting array elements. The [equivalent for Perl 5's `delete`](https://docs.raku.org//language/5to6-perlfunc#delete) points, in fact, to that adverb. You could use [`splice`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/splice) but once again you would have to know the index. The implementation seems to be [this function, `DELETE-POS`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core/Array.pm6#L656), which effectively needs to know the array index.

So the question is, as in the title, is there a way of deleting an array (or, for that matter, associative array) element if you have the handle of just the element itself, not its index?

Comment: As the error message hopefully makes clear, the syntax `$foo:bar` is a single identifier, not an identifier coupled with a `:delete` adverb. Syntactically, the `:delete` must follow an explicit subscript operator (eg `[...]`) to be interpreted as an adverb. I'm guessing you knew that but thought I'd comment for anyone else reading later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends on what you call `delete`.  Internally, on arrays, doing a `DELETE-POS` binds the element in the array to `nqp::null`, which will discard any container living at that position.  At the HLL level, this is represented by the type of the array:

```
my Str @letters = <a b c>;
@letters[1]:delete;
say @letters;   # [a (Str) c]
```

However you can achieve the same effect by assigning `Nil`:

```
my Str @letters = <a b c>;
@letters[1] = Nil;
say @letters;   # [a (Str) c]
```

In this case, the container at that element stays the same, you just let it revert to its "natural" state.  And if you're content with that type of deletion, you can also use that in your loop:

```
my Str @letters = <a b c>;
$_ = Nil if $_ eq "b" for @letters;
say @letters;   # [a (Str) c]
```

When I said: revert to its natural state, this also includes any default value:

```
my Str @letters is default<foo> = <a b c>;
$_ = Nil if $_ eq "b" for @letters;
say @letters;   # [a foo c]
```

If you want to really eradicate the elements from the list *without* keeping the existing elements at their positions, you can of course use `grep`:

```
my @letters = <a b c>;
@letters .= grep: * ne "b";
say @letters;  # [a c]
```

But that does not seem like what you intended.

Answer (score 5):

Please read Lizmat's answer for thoughtful and helpful analysis of your titular question in which she pays appropriate attention to the ambiguity of the English word "deleting".

Here's one way to massage one of the suggestions in her answer back into use of the `:delete` adverb so that the final `@letters` remains the same array with the first element `:delete`'d so the result is the same as your original (`[(Any) b c]`):

```
my @letters = <a b c>;
.[.grep: 'a', :k]:delete given @letters;
say @letters;
```

The `:k` adverb on the `grep` tells it you want the result to be the index.